# Converting indexed table to keyed table in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm a newbie in Lua.

I wonder how to convert indexed table to a key-based table.

For example, Let's say I have the following table.

```
t = {5, 6, 7, 8}
```

Now, I understand `t[1]` is 5, `t[2]` is 6, `t[3]` is 7, and `t[4]` is 8.

What should I do to convert the table `t` to the following key-based style? (without re-constructing the table again)

```
t = {x=5, y=6, z=7, w=8}
```

What would be the most simplest and performant solution to do this?

Comment: "key-based style": Surely not what you mean but (making the point that a table without keys is an empty table), a table with the same key-value pairs written in a different style: `t = {[1] = 5, [2] = 6, [3] = 7, [4] = 8}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
t = {5, 6, 7, 8}
f = {"x", "y", "z", "w"}

for k=1,#t do
    t[f[k]]=t[k]
    t[k]=nil
end

for k,v in pairs(t) do
    print(k,v)
end
```